Retrofighters Hunter USB joystick failed after update
RetroFighters Hunter joystick worked before update to 24.04 kernel 6.8.0-49-generic. Now, on connection, it gives the following and the manufacturer are scratching their heads about this also. I've been reading and others are having trouble with USB devices reporting similar baud rate failures, but no one seems to have a resolution...
2024-12-03T05:37:48.089783+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: usb 1-6.4: new full-speed USB device number 74 using xhci_hcd
2024-12-03T05:37:48.194752+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: usb 1-6.4: New USB device found, idVendor=057e, idProduct=2009, bcdDevice= 2.00
2024-12-03T05:37:48.194789+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: usb 1-6.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
2024-12-03T05:37:48.194793+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: usb 1-6.4: Product: Pro Controller
2024-12-03T05:37:48.194795+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: usb 1-6.4: Manufacturer: Nintendo Co., Ltd.
2024-12-03T05:37:48.194797+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: usb 1-6.4: SerialNumber: 000000000001
2024-12-03T05:37:48.202769+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: input: Nintendo Co., Ltd. Pro Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.4/1-6.4:1.0/0003:057E:2009.0017/input/input49
2024-12-03T05:37:48.204011+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: hid-generic 0003:057E:2009.0017: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [Nintendo Co., Ltd. Pro Controller] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.4/input0
2024-12-03T05:37:48.238771+00:00 mich-desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 74: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.4"
2024-12-03T05:37:48.238872+00:00 mich-desktop mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 74 was not an MTP device
2024-12-03T05:37:48.273705+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: nintendo 0003:057E:2009.0017: hidraw7: USB HID v81.11 Joystick [Nintendo Co., Ltd. Pro Controller] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.4/input0
2024-12-03T05:37:50.433793+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: nintendo 0003:057E:2009.0017: Failed to set baudrate; ret=-110
2024-12-03T05:37:50.433819+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: nintendo 0003:057E:2009.0017: Failed to initialize controller; ret=-110
2024-12-03T05:37:50.435840+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: nintendo 0003:057E:2009.0017: probe - fail = -110
2024-12-03T05:37:50.435876+00:00 mich-desktop kernel: nintendo: probe of 0003:057E:2009.0017 failed with error -110
2024-12-03T05:37:50.470710+00:00 mich-desktop (udev-worker)[991088]: js0: Process '/usr/bin/jscal-restore /dev/input/js0' failed with exit code 1.

